# Weak-Baire Spaces

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, baire-category

I define a topological space $(X,\tau)$ to be a weak-Baire space if every intersection of a countable collection of dense open sets is non-empty.  This is a natural weakening of the usual notion of Baire space, where the intersection is required to be dense rather than merely non-empty. What can we say about these spaces? Have they been studied?

Thanks

EDIT: I'm working in descriptive set theory (hence mainly on Polish spaces), and in many results I've encountered it is used the fact that any two dense $G_\delta$ sets have non-empty intersection. This is a weak consequence of the fact that Polish spaces are Baire spaces (by the Baire category theorem), and I wondered whether we could extend this fact to a wider known (studied) class of spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is straightforward to see that a topological space is *weak-Baire* as defined above, iff the space is not meagre in itself. Hence these are exactly the spaces of second category (in itself).

Comment: And if the OP wants a reference, it's Theorem 25.2 in Willard.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of these spaces having been defined/studied before.

There are some trivial examples: any space with an isolated point will be "weak-Baire" (properties with that name *have* been defined I think; and many strengthenings too, based on topological games e.g.). I think preservation results will be scarse (not of closed or open subspaces), not products or continuous images etc. And what's the use of this property? It doesn't allow the useful existence results that BAire spaces have, I think.